# Printing dynamic django view template

Tags: python, django, printing

I'm working on a django app. I have a page that displays a log of items, and each item has a "Print label" link. At the moment, clicking the link displays the label for that particular item in a popup screen, but does not send the label to a printer. The view function behind the "Print label" link is shown below:

```
@login_required
def print_label(request, id):
     s = Item.objects.get(pk = id)
     return render_to_response('templates/label.html', {'s': s}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The HTML for the label is shown below:

```
{% load humanize %}
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        div{
            min-width: 350px;
            max-width: 350px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        body{
            font-family: Arial;
            width: 370px;
            height: 560px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="labelHeader">
        <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/label-header.png" width="350px">
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <p></p>
    <div id="destinationAddress">
        <span style="font-size: xx-large; font-weight: bold;">{{ s.item_number }}</span> 
        </p>
        DESTINATION:
        <br/>
        <strong>{{s.full_name}}</strong><br/>
        <strong>{{ s.address }}</strong><br/>
        <strong>{{s.city}}, {{s.state}}</strong><br/>
        <strong>Tel: {{s.telephone}}</strong>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <hr/>
    <div id="labelfooter">
        <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/label-footer.png" width="350px">
    </div>
</body>
```

My question is, how can I also send the label displayed to a printer in the same function? I researched and found some libraries (like xhtml2pdf, webkit2png, pdfcrowd, etc), but they'll create a pdf or image file of the label and I'll have to send it to a printer. Is it possible to send straight to a printer without creating a pdf copy of the label? If so, please show me how to achieve this.

Your answers and suggestions are highly welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, as this is a Django app, it's the *client's* printer that you need to use. The only way to do this is to tell the user's browser to print. You will need to use Javascript for this: `window.print()`.

Comment: ..and a [print stylesheet](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/) to go with it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for the tip. It really helped. I thought it would require some server-side Python scripting, but the Javascript works fine.